# Prevent Simple Macro Substitution

Tags: c++, c

How does one prevent simple macro substitution?

e.g.

```
#define number 0x10

int number = 0x5;
```

I know this can be done for function-style macros, like `min` and `max`, by surrounding the macro with parentheses (thus, separating it from the adjacent parentheses that would've been used for the args):

```
#define max(...)

void (max)();
```

My current method is to push the macro value, undefine it, use it, then pop the original value.

Comment: Macro substitution is made by the preprocessor, before compilation then. The only way to prevent it is to not use macros. Use global constant instead, or functions.

Comment: Even if you managed to get the declaration to work you'd still have the same problem every time you used the variable

Comment: in my why-not-use-macros-list this is on the top rank. There is no clean solution. Whatever hack you use, not using the macro is the better option to avoid name clashes

Comment: There's a reason naming conventions arose. Macros are almost universally UPPER_CASE precisely to avoid such clashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard way for this but you can do the following:

```
#define number 0x10

#pragma push_macro("number")
#undef number
int number = 0x5;
#pragma pop_macro("number")
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't prevent macro substitution.

That's one of the reasons why macros are usually all caps:

```
#define NUMBER 0x10

int number = 0x5;    // no problem here.
```

Even this can be done of course:

```
int number = NUMBER;  // even this can be done of course
```

Answer (score 3):

I would advise using `const` variables when you want to define constants instead of using macros. And to avoid name collisions maybe just add some prefix or suffix to the name or capitalize the name.
In c++ you can even use `constexpr`.

Comment: `const` variables aren't all the useful in C for this purpose. A `const int` in C is not a constant expression. So you have no choice but use macros (or enumerations) if you need to deal with constant expressions.

Answer (score 0):

The #undef directive undefines a constant or preprocessor macro defined previously using #define.
Refer: https://www.cprogramming.com/reference/preprocessor/undef.html